# Smart penalty term for constant sparsity of matrix columns

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, sparse-matrices

I am looking, in an convex optimization problem, for a smart way to write a penalty term $Reg(A)$ (where $A$ is the coefficients matrix of the data $X$ w.r.t. the learned dictionary $D$, $A=D^{T}X$), that enforces **constant column sparsity** on $A$ : 
\begin{equation}
argmin ||X-DA||^{2}_{F} +\lambda Reg(A)
\end{equation}

Any idea on how to write $Reg(A)$?

Thank you!

Comment: That's not actually convex, as I hope you know. And if there's one thing worse in practice than trying to enforce $\mathop{\textrm{card}}(x)\leq k$, it's $\mathop{\textrm{card}}(x)=k$. And if there's anything worse than those, it's doing the same multiple times in the same model---e.g. once for each column of matrix. I hate to be a spoil sport but this is as about as hard a problem as they come.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you say there is no hope even of I use l1 norm and the coefficient matrix is  of the order 100 times 1000?

Comment: You could always try a MILP formulation, but no, I do not see a practical solution here.